# $B$ an $A$-algebra and $\text{End}(B)$ an $A$-module

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules

Are the following two statements equivalent?

- $A$ and $B$ are rings, and $B$ is an $A$-algebra
- $A$ and $B$ are rings, and $\text{End}(B)$ is an $A$-module?

It seems that they are, but I'd never though about it before, so I wanted to make sure. Mainly it makes sense since in the first dot point, $B$ receives a 'scalar' multiplication from $A$, and in the latter, elements of $A$ act as linear operators.

If this is true, is it interesting for any reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If $B$ is a (left) $A$-algebra you get a structure of (right) $A$-module on ${\rm End}(B)$ by
  $$
  (\phi\cdot a)(b):=\phi(a\cdot b)
  $$
- If ${\rm End}(B)$ is a (left) $A$-module, then you get a multiplication by $a\in A$ in $B$ on the right as
  $$
  b\cdot a:=(a\cdot{\rm id}_B)(b)
  $$
  that makes $B$ an $A$-algebra.

Same things inverting right and left.